# Unable to create customers in Stripe using WSO2 APIM

Tags: wso2, stripe-payments, wso2-api-manager

I am trying to use the **monetization** feature in **WSO2 APIM**. I am testing it out with **default** *Stripe* as its billing engine. I have followed this documentation for the configuration [WSO2 APIM Monetization](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/design/api-monetization/monetizing-an-api/#!). I have commented out the existing workflow definition for **SubscriptionCreation** and **SubscriptionDeletion** and added the definition mentioned in the steps.

The current workflow definition after the update looks like this ->

```
<WorkFlowExtensions>
<ApplicationCreation executor="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.ApplicationCreationSimpleWorkflowExecutor"/>
<!--ApplicationCreation executor="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.ApplicationCreationApprovalWorkflowExecutor"/-->
<ProductionApplicationRegistration executor="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.ApplicationRegistrationSimpleWorkflowExecutor"/>
<!--ProductionApplicationRegistration executor="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.ApplicationRegistrationApprovalWorkflowExecutor"/-->
<SandboxApplicationRegistration executor="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.ApplicationRegistrationSimpleWorkflowExecutor"/>
<!--SandboxApplicationRegistration executor="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.ApplicationRegistrationApprovalWorkflowExecutor"/-->
<!--<SubscriptionCreation executor="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.SubscriptionCreationSimpleWorkflowExecutor"/>-->
<SubscriptionCreation executor="org.wso2.apim.monetization.impl.workflow.StripeSubscriptionCreationWorkflowExecutor"/>
<!--SubscriptionCreation executor="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.SubscriptionCreationApprovalWorkflowExecutor"/-->
```

Subscription Update ->

```
<SubscriptionUpdate executor="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.SubscriptionUpdateSimpleWorkflowExecutor"/>
<!--SubscriptionUpdate executor="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.SubscriptionUpdateApprovalWorkflowExecutor"/-->
<!--SubscriptionUpdate executor="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.SubscriptionUpdateWSWorkflowExecutor">
     <Property name="serviceEndpoint">http://localhost:9765/services/SubscriptionApprovalWorkFlowProcess/</Property>
     <Property name="username">username</Property>
     <Property name="password">password</Property>
     <Property name="callbackURL">https://host:port/services/WorkflowCallbackService</Property>
</SubscriptionUpdate-->
<UserSignUp executor="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.UserSignUpSimpleWorkflowExecutor"/>
<!--UserSignUp executor="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.UserSignUpApprovalWorkflowExecutor"/-->

<!--
***NOTE:***
    Users of deletion workflows are expected to implement their own deletion workflow executors and services.
    By default API Manager only implements the core functionalities required to support deletion workflows and
    simple deletion workflow executors. Default WS deletion workflow implementations are not available with the
    distribution.
-->

<!--<SubscriptionDeletion executor="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.SubscriptionDeletionSimpleWorkflowExecutor"/>-->
<SubscriptionDeletion executor="org.wso2.apim.monetization.impl.workflow.StripeSubscriptionDeletionWorkflowExecutor"/>
<!--SubscriptionDeletion executor="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.SubscriptionDeletionSimpleWorkflowExecutor">
     <Property name="serviceEndpoint">http://host:port/services/SubscriptionApprovalWorkFlowProcess/</Property>
     <Property name="username">username</Property>
     <Property name="password">password</Property>
     <Property name="callbackURL">https://host:port/services/WorkflowCallbackService</Property>
</SubscriptionDeletion -->
<ApplicationDeletion executor="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.ApplicationDeletionSimpleWorkflowExecutor"/>
<!--ApplicationDeletion executor="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.ApplicationDeletionSimpleWorkflowExecutor">
     <Property name="serviceEndpoint">http://host:port/services/ApplicationApprovalWorkFlowProcess/</Property>
     <Property name="username">username</Property>
     <Property name="password">password</Property>
     <Property name="callbackURL">https://host:port/services/WorkflowCallbackService</Property>
</ApplicationDeletion-->

<!-- Publisher related workflows -->
<APIStateChange executor="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.APIStateChangeSimpleWorkflowExecutor" />
<!--APIStateChange executor="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.APIStateChangeApprovalWorkflowExecutor">
    <Property name="stateList">Created:Publish,Published:Block</Property>
</APIStateChange-->

<APIProductStateChange executor="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.APIProductStateChangeSimpleWorkflowExecutor" />
<!--APIProductStateChange executor="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.APIProductStateChangeApprovalWorkflowExecutor">
    <Property name="stateList">Created:Publish,Published:Block</Property>
</APIProductStateChange-->
```

`

When I try to monetize a policy or when I try to subscribe API to an application using the monetized policy, I get the following error ->

```
ERROR - StripeSubscriptionCreationWorkflowExecutor Error while creating a customer in Stripe for username

ERROR - APIConsumerImpl Could not execute Workflow
org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.WorkflowException: Error while creating a customer in Stripe for username

Caused by: com.stripe.exception.ApiConnectionException: IOException during API request to Stripe (https://api.stripe.com): HTTPS hostname wrong:  should be <api.stripe.com> Please check your internet connection and try again. If this problem persists,you should check Stripe's service status at https://twitter.com/stripestatus, or let us know at support@stripe.com.
```

It seems the issue is due to the workflow update, but I couldn't figure out the exact issue.

**Update**: -
I tried removing the workflow changes, and with that configuration, I am able to create an API subscription (Hostname error occurs sometimes and sometimes it does not) but even if the subscription is created respective customer is not getting created on the connected Stripe account.

Comment: Can you add `StripeSubscriptionCreationWorkflowExecutor` related definition as well? It seems you have missed it. I can see only `SubscriptionDeletion` tag

Comment: @ArunanSugunakumar updated the workflow definition. `StripeSubscriptionCreationWorkflowExecutor` was there in my configuration but was missing in the question. The issue still persists.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your server is unable to communicate with Stripe API endpoint (https://api.stripe.com). You might want to add [Stripe domains](https://stripe.com/docs/ips#stripe-domains) to your server's allowlist.

Comment: Tried adding "api.stripe.com" and also other domains in the allowlist, still getting the same error. When I tried hitting "api.stripe.com" in any browser, I am getting -> {
  "error": {
    "message": "Unrecognized request URL (GET: /). If you are trying to list objects, remove the trailing slash. If you are trying to retrieve an object, make sure you passed a valid (non-empty) identifier in your code. Please see https://stripe.com/docs or we can help at https://support.stripe.com/.",
    "type": "invalid_request_error"
  }
}

The same error occurs even in other machines.